# Login system is set up with passport, how do I implement a reset password system?

Tags: angularjs, express, passport.js

I have a frontend in Angular, separate backend generated with Keystone and an API which is a regular express app which uses passport for login and register.

Now I want to implement a system that the user can reset his password, by clicking on a link in a generated personal email.

I tried using:

[Stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/angularjs/guide/password_reset.html)

[userapp - reset password section](https://app.userapp.io/#/home/)

But for both u need to use their whole login system, I can't just use only the password reset section.

How can I "manually" implement this or is there any module which takes care of only the password reset and not the whole login system?

Comment: What is the point of using a login system if you still need to reset manually? Why not let the system do everything?

Comment: Yeah I know this now, but redoing the whole system is alot of work now and I can do this. But maybe I can just do the password resetting separate.